# convert .obj and .mtl file with multiple materials to json

Tags: three.js, .obj, meshlab

I have a .obj, .mtl files with multiple materials
for a specified material, I want to print the vertices and their corresponding uv coords.
Is there a way to e.g. parse a .obj, and .mtl file and export them to json?
When using

- wavefront-obj-parser
- PyWavefront
- meshlab
  All these tools generate a json file I think that the data is partial - I don't see the materials in there.

---

EDIT:

I tested with an example [3d model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/olielhrig7n8dmf/foo1.zip?dl=0)

step1: converted the .obj and .mtl with multiple materials into a .json file

- Added the addon to Blender (version 2.76b) as instructed in [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender)
- In Blender, imported the .obj, .mtl (the model shows up but not the material textures)
- In Blender exported to Three.json (see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/esehjqmnrvveqtb/foo1.json?dl=0))

step2: loaded the generated .json file (foo1.json) within a threejs example

- Used the example webgl_loader_json_objconverter.html from [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_json_objconverter.html)
- Replaced Female02_slim.js with foo1.json
- The model Male02_dds.js is loaded but the foo1.json is not and I'm getting an error message: `TypeError: vertices is undefined`

Some links indicate that Blender Exporter and Json File Loader are not so reliable (see [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/13375), [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11817), [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11426), and [here in general](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12903))
Is there any other converter from .obj, .mtl to .json that anybody can recommend? (not necessarily in relation to three.js)

Assuming that I can convert to glTF format, is there a tool, (e.g. a command line utility in python) that will let me specify a material index and get the vertices and corresponding uv coords for this material?

---

Solved:
**I ended up using meshlab plugin export to json. It works (almost) fine for me**

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use Blender and THREE JS plugin (exporter):

https://www.blender.org/

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender

Exported file have materials as array if you use JSON Loader function

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/JSONLoader

Comment: I used Blender and THREE JS plugin (exporter) as you suggested but I'm still not getting the materials into the json file. I updated the original post and added the example .obj, .mtl, and .json files.
Thanks